# Random Generation of Property From Dictionary Swift 2

Tags: swift, xcode, class, dictionary, random

I wanted to ask a question that has had me stuck for quite some time.

I have created a class with specific properties, and created a few objects to go with it (only 2 are shown in example)

```
 class ShapeColour : NSObject {
        var colour:String
        var shape:String
        var image:UIImage

init(color: String, shape: String, image: UIImage) {
            self.colour = color
            self.shape = shape
            self.image = image
        }

    }


    //Blue Square

    let blueSquareObject =  ShapeColour(color: "blue", shape: "square", image: UIImage(named: "BlueSquare.jpg")!)

    //Red Square

    let redSquareObject = ShapeColour(color: "red", shape: "sqaure", image: UIImage(named: "RedSquare.jpg")!)
```

Next, I created a dict containing all the objects (again, only 2 are shown) and wrote a line of code to try randomly select one of the objects.

```
let allMainShape = [0:blueSquareObject,1:blueCircleObject]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allMainShape.count)))
```

I want to know how I can randomly generate one of the objects, and from that generation extract one of the attribute. I thought it would be something like this:

```
print"Colour is \(allMainShape.color[randomIndex])"
```

Thanks,
Any help would be appreciated greatly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `allMainShape[randomIndex].color` not `allMainShape.color[randomIndex]`. Also instead of creating `Dictionary` with `Integer` key you need to use Array of `ShapeColour`.

So you need to try like this way.

```
let allMainShape = [blueSquareObject, blueCircleObject] //Gives you `[ShapeColour]`

//Now get random object from it.
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allMainShape.count)))
print"Colour is \(allMainShape[randomIndex].color)"
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Would it be possible to use the image attribute to change the image of a image view? E.g: Imageview.image = uiimage(named: "\(Allmainshape[randomindex].image") ? Or would what result in an error as the image name attribute is just a string? Thanks!

Comment: For that it is simply `imageview.image = Allmainshape[randomindex].image` because you are already have UIImage instance not the string one.